# How to make Maven fail if a passed flag is invalid?

Tags: maven

```
mvn install -DSkipTests
```

Will happily run, while running tests (as the correct capitalization is `-DskipTests`). I'd like to immediately know that `-DSkipTests` does nothing, alerting me I've made a typo. Is this possible? Why does it not work this way to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/index.html). It provides the [Require Property rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) which enables you to check if a property is set, and evaluate its value againsts a set of values or regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem: With `-D`, you just specify arbitrary properties.

Maven does not know if any of your Maven plugins consumes them.

Comment: But would the compute time required to check if the plugins consume them be anything substantial? Forgive me if I'm gravely misunderstanding how maven works, I really only interact with it when things are going wrong. Would it be correct to say maven could reasonably provide this as a configuration, but doesn't?

Comment: Partly. You can inject properties as parameters to plugins, and it would be relatively easy to check that. But some plugins or enforcer rules evaluate properties in their code (i.e. by reading the property list of the project), and this is difficult because in extreme cases it would mean to really analyse the Java code of the plugins.